# Sharepoint 365 teamsite - Ondrive for Business syncing - confusion with OneDrive app

Tags: sync, onedrive, sharepoint, office365

So a user has documents in both OneDrive for Business and a Sharepoint teams site.

The "OneDrive" app is syncing both to different folders.  One is the "OneDrive for Business" folder and the other is the "Sharepoint" folder - these 2 folders are in the left panel under Favorites in Explorer.

When clicking on the "Onedrive" app, it automatically opens the OneDrive for Business folder.

This is very confusing to the user.

The Sharepiont Team folder should be the default folder when clicking on Onedrive.
When double clicking on the OneDrive app, the default selection is "open your OneDrive for Business folder" - eventhough Onedrive is syncing the Sharepoint team site - and the "onedrive for Business" feature in O365 is secondary to them - which they rarely use.

How can the OneDrive app open the Sharepoint folder by default instead of OneDrive for Business folder to prevent this confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you shouldn't get your hopes up for a positive answer. Microsoft seem very keen to draw customers in to using OneDrives (the SharePoint space that is). Presumably because once you have used lots of your unlimited space it will be all but impossible to leave the platform.

Microsoft have acknowledged unredeemable issues with the OneDrive for Business client and will be replacing it before the end of this year with a new client based on the current OneDrive (consumer version). This will allow a more reliable sync and also allow selective sync (critically important on unlimited accounts with SSD based laptops!)

The limitation you mention however is not, I think, in the requirements for the new client and perhaps you should raise it as a need on their forums. They are being remarkably responsive at present so you might even get a result.

Other issues with OneDrive for Business include the repeated and common failure of sync for teamsites and the not quite so common (but not rare either) failure of sync for personal OneDrive's.